# Why does this statement only work with a WHERE?

Tags: sql

I have a Customers table and an orders table. Not all customers placed an order, so not all customer IDs are on the orders table. I want my result to show ONLY the values from the customer table who did not place an order, so the orderID column should show as null. The following code works:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, o.OrderID
  FROM Customers c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders o
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID WHERE o.OrderID IS NULL
```

But the one I tried originally doesn't:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, o.OrderID
  FROM Customers c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders o
ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID AND o.OrderID IS NULL
```

This one instead shows all the values on the customers table but ALL of them have null on for their orderID

I don't think I really understand the difference, since I feel like it would make sense for them to both return the same thing.

Comment: I understand intuitively why you would think that, but I think the reason is that 'ON' is used to join tables ON a given condition. What you are are trying to do is look for rows WHERE a condition is true. I don't know if this is anywhere near the truth, but it's how I've come to think of it and know when to use what.

Comment: the AND o.OrderID is the one that's messing it up. It would work correctly till it hits the AND.... condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the nature of an outer join (in this case a left join). A left join takes your main table (Customers), matches it by the criteria to the joined table (Orders). For each row in Customers that doesn't have a match, unlike an inner join, it doesn't remove the row. Instead, it adds all the fields from Orders but puts null in them.

Look at this example:

```
 Table A           Table B
┌──────┬──────┐ ┌──────┬──────┐
│field1│field2│ │field3│field4│
├──────┼──────┤ ├──────┼──────┤
│A     │1     │ │1     │One   │
│B     │2     │ │3     │Three │
│C     │3     │ └──────┴──────┘
└──────┴──────┘
```

The tables' inner join (between field2 and field3) is:

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│field1│field2│field3│field4│
├──────┼──────┤──────┼──────┤
│A     │1     │1     │One   │
│C     │3     │3     │Three │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

But the tables' outer join has to give you every record, and if there is no match, put nulls instead.

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│field1│field2│field3│field4│
├──────┼──────┤──────┼──────┤
│A     │1     │1     │One   │
│B     │2     │NULL  │NULL  │⬅︎ No match
│C     │3     │3     │Three │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Now what would happen if there are no matches in table2 at all? For example, if you added an impossible condition in the ON clause? Then all the records in the result would look like the "No match"

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│field1│field2│field3│field4│
├──────┼──────┤──────┼──────┤
│A     │1     │NULL  │NULL  │⬅︎ No match (because of impossible condition)
│B     │2     │NULL  │NULL  │⬅︎ No match (because of impossible condition)
│C     │3     │NULL  │NULL  │⬅︎ No match (because of impossible condition)
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

So it doesn't matter if there was no match because there was no record in Table2 with the given ID, or if there was no match because you added an impossible condition. The result of an outer join is that the fields that were supposed to come from Table2 would be replaced with nulls. Because that's how an outer join is defined.

---

Now to the real world tables:

You don't actually have any records in Orders whose OrderID is null (unless you designed it very badly). So if you put that condition in the ON clause, it will find no records that meet your criteria.

In such a case, because this is an outer (left) join, you get all the origintal Customers records, and because there were no matches, each of them has the fields from Orders all null.

In the case where you put the condition in the `WHERE`, you were actually making good use of this behaviour of a left join. You were matching each customer with its order. If there was a match - fine, you got the actual order ID. But in cases there was no match - the ones you are looking for - it adds a null order ID.

The where clause then tells it to give you only the records where that happened. That is, the records that did not have a matching order in Orders.

Comment: Okay, I kinda understand now why the AND wouldn't work how I want it to. It would only look at the orders table, and look at the ordersID column and would find that none are null. But I don't understand why it sets them as null @RealSkeptic

Comment: @FrostyStraw The NULL value in OrderID means that no record matches criteria `ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID AND o.OrderID IS NULL`.

Comment: @FrostyStraw I added some explanation about the nature of outer joins to my answer, which I hope will help you understand the reason.

Comment: I got a lot of good answers but you drawing out the tables and explaining them made me understand it very well @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 6):

It is important to pont out that the two queries are *very* different.  The first query is:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, o.OrderID
FROM Customers c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE o.OrderID IS NULL;
```

It returns all customers that have no corresponding orders (or `o.OrderId` is null).  It does that because the `left outer join` keeps all rows in the first table.  If there is no match, then all columns from the second table are `NULL` and the `where` clause would choose these columns.

The second query:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName, o.OrderID
FROM Customers c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID AND
        o.OrderID IS NULL;
```

finds all rows all customers and also gets order information where `OrderId` is null, if any such records exist.  There is no filtering of `Customers`, because the `left outer join` guarantees that all rows from the first table are in the result set.

I would be surprised if a field called `OrderId` ever took on `NULL` values.  But, each query is valid SQL and each does something useful.  Only one of them, however, does what you intend.

Answer (score 3):

Using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you get all records from `Customers` table. So your `AND o.OrderID IS NULL` condition filters only records from `Orders` table but not the records from `Customers`. But what you need is to filter `Customers` table and it does not work because of the type of the `JOIN`.

Meanwhile using `WHERE` condition is applied to the entire recordset regardless on the type of JOIN. Try to replace `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `INNER JOIN` and you get the same results for both SELECTs.

In your second SELECT you get NULL values for `o.OrderID` because you specified that it should be NULL in your condition `AND o.OrderID IS NULL`. No such record exists in `Orders` table and thus the NULL value means that no record matches criteria `ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID AND o.OrderID IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply just not how SQL is designed. From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

> The conditional_expr used with ON is any conditional expression of the
>   form that can be used in a WHERE clause. Generally, you should use the
>   ON clause for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the
>   WHERE clause to restrict which rows you want in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is POST joining of the Tables. The second is part of the join.

So to put in English.

First:

```
 Get CustomerID, Name, and OrderID from
 Customers Link to Orders where CustomerID matches
 Show where link failed
```

Second:

```
Get CustomerID, Name, and OrderID from
Customers Link to Orders where CustomerID matches and Order ID is null
```

All links fail in the second, leaving nothing to filter your results.

Answer (score 1):

For the second query your join condition is false for every row. If the Order table has a CustomerId then it will have an OrderId also. After every row is excluded the "left" part of the join is just bringing back all the excluded rows from the left table (Customer). In this case it's bring back all of them.

For the first query it's only false on the rows you want, so the left join just restores those rows. And then the where condition can take out the rows you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Create table ##Customer (Id nvarchar(5))
Create table ##Order (Order_No int, Id nvarchar(5))

Insert into ##customer values ('A'), ('B'), ('C')

Insert into ##Order values (1, 'A'),(2, 'B'),(3, 'B')

Select c.* from ##customer c 
left join ##Order o
on c.Id = o.id where o.Order_No is null

Select c.id, o.order_no from ##customer c 
left join ##Order o
on c.Id = o.id and o.Order_No is null

Select c.id, o.order_no from ##customer c 
left join ##Order o
on c.Id = o.id and o.Order_No is not null

try it yourself you will see the difference, where clause is giving a filter

Answer (score 1):

A LEFT OUTER JOIN preserves the unmatched rows from the left (first) table, joining them with a NULL row in the shape of the right (second)  table.
Let's take a concrete example.
Say, Customers table has `{c1,"n1"}, {c2,"n2"}`
and Orders has `{c1, o1}`
1st case:
Left outer join will result:

```
{c1,"n1", o1}, {c2,"n2", null}
```

Now, you know the difference of where and "AND". Where finds out where you have null orderid, for AND, there is no such case where customer id matched and order id is null